# Negative lookbehind in regex, followed by optional spaces

Tags: regex, grep, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to write a regex that matches B, when it is not preceded by A -- regardless of whether there is intervening whitespace.

So, I tried this negative lookbehind, and tested it in regex101.com:

```
(?<!A)\s*B
```

This causes "AB" not to be matched, which is good, but "A B" does result in a match, which is not what I want.

I am not exactly sure why this is. It has something to do with the fact that \s* matches the empty string "", and you can say that there are, as such, infinity matches of \s* between A and B. But why does this affect "A B" but not "AB"?

Is the following regex a proper solution, and if so, why exactly does it fix the problem?

```
(?<![A\s])\s*B
```

Note that the variable-length thing I'm looking for is part of the match, not part of the negative lookbehind itself -- so this is **not a duplicate of the other question**.

Comment: Are you going to use lookbehind in `grep`?

Comment: You need to put `\s*` inside the negative lookbehind. But quantifiers aren't allowed inside lookbehinds.

Comment: Yes, I will be using this in grep, using Perl regexes. Aka `grep -P`

Comment: Why do I need to put the \s* inside the negative lookbehind? I have no problems with there being whitespace as part of the match. Note that this isn't a duplicate of the other question, since the variable length thing I'm looking for is **part of the match**, not part of the negative lookbehind.